# jquery ui date picker not allow 2 weeks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how would I use the jQuery UI date picker and limit it to where no dates can be selected before 2 weeks from the current day? We allow vacation stops on our service but the user has to give 2 weeks notice. Is this possible with the date picker?

Thanks for any suggestions and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -14, maxDate: "+14D" });
```

Comment: Hey, thank you this did start to do what I need it to do. Only thing is that it gave options for 14 days before today. What I need is that the first option that is available is 14 days from today. I tried to play around with your code but it was not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I played around with this more and got it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See the minDate/maxDate Options:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker